# Is there an implementation of SIFT descriptor for Point Cloud?

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, sift, feature-descriptor

Does anyone know where I can find an implementation of SIFT descriptors for Point Cloud? Point Cloud Library has code for SIFT keypoints detection that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

PCL has implementations for RIFT and NARF features/descriptors, which are similar to SIFT (see https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/wiki/Overview-and-Comparison-of-Features). I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but I think it could still be useful for you.